# How to programmatically display a SSL certificate's trust in iOS

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios

I'd like to display the SSL certificate a server send within an iOS application, so the user can accept/cancel the connection or alter the trust settings.

On OS X there is the [SFCertificateView](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Security/Reference/SecurityInterfaceFramework/Classes/SFCertificateView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003983) class and the corresponding SFCertificatePanel and [SFCertificateTrustPanel](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Security/Reference/SecurityInterfaceFramework/Classes/SFCertificateTrustPanel_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003982) classes.

Do you know a corresponding class/function for iOS? Preferably "legal", meaning: no private calls, since Apple is known to reject them for App Store submission.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: how to display a certificate using SFCertificateView in MAC? Any idea...   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68906064/open-view-certificate-programatically-in-mac

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't anything built-in. You can accept iOS's default trust evaluation, or your app can override the OS and decide to accept or reject a presented certificate itself. If you want to involve the user in that decision, you need to design your own UI.