# Open/View certificate programatically on a macOS

Tags: swift, macos

Is there any option available in macOS to display a certificate programatically.

Something similar to this:

[image]

Comment: Look at SFCertificateTrustPanel https://developer.apple.com/documentation/securityinterface/sfcertificatetrustpanel

Comment: anyway i got the answer from @MarekH ..Thanks.     SFCertificatePanel.shared().beginSheet(for: nil, modalDelegate: nil, didEnd: nil, contextInfo: nil, certificates: [seccert!], showGroup: false)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @MarekH ,SecCertificateCreateWithData can be used to display certificates from application

```
 DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    let certData = //read certificate file
                            let cert = SecCertificateCreateWithData(kCFAllocatorDefault, certData! as CFData)
                            SFCertificatePanel.shared().beginSheet(for: self.view.window, modalDelegate: nil, didEnd: nil, contextInfo: nil, certificates: [cert!], showGroup: false)
                        }
```